# File not deleting in if statement

Tags: java, file, if-statement

I’m trying to delete the text files that are < 100 words.  I have an `int` called `words` that counts the words in each text file and displays the amount for each text file. `TXTResultsFile` specifies the location where the text file is saved. That works well! I have an if statement that is shown below but it doesn’t delete the files that are < 100 words. I have no errors when I run this but it also doesn't delete the text file. Thanks!

```
String s = "";
int words = 0;

while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {                   

    String[] lineWordList = s.split(" ");                   
    words = words + lineWordList.length;

}

System.out.println ("Total Number of Words for " +TXTResultsFile  + " = " + words); 

if (words > 100){ 
    System.out.println ("Keep this text file");
}
else {
    file.delete();
    System.out.println("File has been deleted");    
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of File.delete() to understand what it does. Prefer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29 instead.

Comment: sorry file is: `file = new File (TXTResultsFile);`

Comment: `br.close();`  after the while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the file is already open. Close the stream which uses the file before deleting it.

```
else {
    br.close();
    file.delete();
    System.out.println("File has been deleted");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a file stream is open, you are not able to delete the file as it is being used by Java. I assume that `file` is an open stream, and it makes sense for the code not to work.

To negate the problem, close the stream before the `file.delete();` statement with: `file.close();`. This will close the stream and allow the file to be deleted.